# "Directed at" vs. "directed towards"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

These seem to be interchangeable. Are these both  grammatically correct? Is there any difference at all?

When are "at" and "towards" interchangeable?

Answer (score 9):

There is a slight difference in meaning between 'at' and 'towards'. 'At' gives an aggressive sense, eg 'His snide remarks were directed at her.' 'Towards' is more neutral, eg 'We must direct our focus towards a more practical aspect of the issue'.
I am not sure whether they are interchangeable, I wouldn't use them as such.

Comment: I agree. If something is "directed at" something, it is aimed precisely at that one thing and nothing else. If something is "directed towards" something, it is aimed in the direction of that thing, and perhaps other things as well. Though the distinction is not quite as sharp as I may be implying.